# Can't get specific data from JSON object, PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to return specific data from JSON by passing parameters in the url, example below.

```
 http://localhost/api/api.php?post_title=Strawbrerry
```

This does absolutely nothing at all, and would appreciate some advice on how to resolve this....  Please see code below.

```
$connection = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);

if( ! $connection ) die( "Error ".mysqli_connect_error() );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$array_post = array();

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$array_post['post_title'][] = $data['post_title'];
$array_post['post_description'][] = $data['post_description'];
$array_post['post_image'][] = $data['post_image'];
$array_post['posted_by]'][] = $data['posted_by'];
$array_post['[post_date]'][] = $data['post_date'];
}
echo json_encode($array_post);
```

Comment: Where this code is written? in api.php?

Comment: Yes.... api.php display the JSON.

Comment: you want the data whose `post_title` is `Strawbrerry`?

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with the GET parameter. Can you update your question with what precisely you want done with it? Do you want to get posts whose title is exactly 'Strawbrerry' or simply contain 'Strawbrerry'?

Comment: Yes, or any other parameters that a passed to the url

Comment: @JeffLambert Yes, that contain 'Strawberry'.

Comment: What does it mean *“This does absolutely nothing at all”*? With your actual code you must be see all records in posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rely on a URL parameter named `post_title` to give you back post results that contain the word 'Strawberry' in the title, you can modify your current script with something along these lines:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
if(isset($_GET['post_title']) && $_GET['post_title']) {
    $sql .= " WHERE post_title LIKE '%?%'";
    // Use prepared statements here. Don't trust GET parameters
    // to not be SQL injection attempts.
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['post_title']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
} else {
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}

// Here, $result should hold the result set
```

If `post_title` is not set in the URL, nothing changes.  If it is, it modifies the SQL statement you are constructing to include a [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) expression to filter results of the query to only include those whose title contains whatever is passed in through the URL.  Refer to the following manual entries for more information.

- [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)
- [`mysqli_stmt_bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)